# RTF Template Attribute Dynamic Value

Tags: rtf, xml-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

I am trying to create a rtf template for xml publisher. In my table there are some diffrent group listed. I want to give special background color for each group. Color information will come from xml with 'GROUP_COLOR' tag.

Normally this code works perfectly in my template:

```
<xsl:attribute xdofo:ctx="block" name="background-color">#FF420E</xsl:attribute>
```

When try to get color value from xml like below gives error:

```
<xsl:attribute xdofo:ctx="block" name="background-color"><?GROUP_COLOR?></xsl:attribute>
```

How can i overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find solution like below:

```
<xsl:attribute xdofo:ctx="block" name="background-color">
    <xsl:value-of select="GROUP_COLOR"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```